# Ember checkbox click, change event not firing, gives error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have problem during use of checkbox in ember. I have used one boolean property for checked binding. Now i want to fire a event on change of this property or click on checkbox, but when i clicks it doesn't fires any of the event. Even it doesn't calls observer function on change of that property. below is the my code snippet,

in View- observer on  "setAsRecurringAction" checked property or this can be a click event handler.

```
setActionSchedule: function() {
    if (this.get('setAsRecurringAction')) {
        $(".response-container").css({height: '38em'});
    } else {
        $(".response-container").css({height: '19em'});
    }
}.observes('setAsRecurringAction')
```

template-

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox 
     checkedBinding="setAsRecurringAction"
     class="set-recurring"}}
```

and same code with action helper also didn't work,

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox 
    checkedBinding="setAsRecurringAction"
    class="set-recurring"
    action="setActionSchedule"}}
```

- Some more info when i checks the checkbox throws error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined"

thnx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look to the [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/durinthomas/MTLkq/) i just created.

If **setActionSchedule** is defined in a view then your have to change your **checkedBinding path**.

```js
{{view Ember.Checkbox 
    checkedBinding="view.setAsRecurringAction" }}
```

Comment: Ohh it was my mistake, my first code snippet worked only mistake is that "setActionSchedule" was defined in parentView.

Comment: Really thanks ThomasD, i caught my mistake because of your working example only, really thanks.